# Nginx signal process started

Tags: nginx

I cant reach the server from nginx. It keeps telling me this weird signal process started error. I feel like I have tried everything to fix this. Been giving permission to ubuntu where the file is stored. But it comes down to nginx not being able to reach the server on pm2 as pm2 status is fine and I have no clue why.

```
2022/05/18 18:01:36 [notice] 26002#26002: signal process started
2022/05/18 18:02:06 [notice] 26016#26016: signal process started
2022/05/18 18:03:49 [notice] 26045#26045: signal process started
2022/05/18 18:06:15 [notice] 26071#26071: signal process started
2022/05/18 18:06:22 [crit] 26046#26046: *1305 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading) while SSL handshaking, client: 139.99.61.171, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/05/18 18:11:32 [notice] 1107#1107: signal process started
2022/05/18 18:44:13 [notice] 1441#1441: signal process started
2022/05/18 18:50:17 [notice] 1566#1566: signal process started
2022/05/18 19:05:03 [notice] 1878#1878: signal process started
2022/05/18 19:10:26 [notice] 1949#1949: signal process started
2022/05/18 19:12:30 [notice] 1980#1980: signal process started
2022/05/18 19:12:33 [notice] 1988#1988: signal process started
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/log/syslog` for more information on why nginx may be restarting.